# Extract bits that are set into a HashSet<uint>?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a convenient way in c# (using linq or similar) to extract the true bits of a uint into a `HashSet<uint>` ?

Example:

```
  private HashSet<uint> ExtractTrueBitsFromSum(uint sum)
  {

  } 

calling it with 15 returns the set `{1,2,4,8}`
calling it with 23 returns the set `{1,2,4,16}`
calling it with 31 returns the set `{1,2,4,8,16}`
```

Comment: Convenient?  Not really - work out the binary math on paper, then translate your steps to code.  There's probably "clever" way to do it but I would get something that _works_ first then concentrate on making it "better_ (whatever that means to you).

Comment: Why a `HashSet` anyways?  What's the end goal here? What does knowing which bits are set in an integer buy you?

Comment: @DStanley Why should it not be a HashSet... it's impossible to have duplicate values.

Comment: The question is not HashSet vs List. The question he is asking is what are you going do do with this information once you have the HashSet, there may be a better way to reach your end goal.He is checking to see if you have a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What @ScottChamberlain said...  If you _really, really_ want this specific utility than I'm sure someone will provide it. But it sounds like a means to an end, and I suspect you can get what you really need by using binary operators (AND, OR, XOR, etc.) or some other mechanism that are easier to implement and understand.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm in the process of converting a system that used bitfields into a system that uses proper Ids and objects to represent these values. I'm writting adapter code right now to bridge the old way and the new way. Trust me, I need to do this.

Comment: Is a enum with the `Flags` attribute a option? It sounds better suited for what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private HashSet<uint> ExtractTrueBitsFromSum(uint sum) {
    HashSet<uint> result = new HashSet<uint>();
    while(sum>0) {
        uint newSum = sum&(sum-1); // newSum = sum with least significant True bit set to False.
        result.Add(sum^newSum);    // sum^newSum return least significant True bit of sum.
        sum=newSum;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on `int`s:

```
int n = 23;
string str = Convert.ToString(n, 2);


HashSet<int> result = new HashSet<int>(str.Select((c, index) => 
                             int.Parse(c.ToString()) > 0 ? (int)Math.Pow(2, index) : 0));
result.Remove(0);
```

Edit - to account for reversed order of bits:

```
HashSet<int> result = new HashSet<int>(str.Reverse().Select((c, index) => 
                             int.Parse(c.ToString()) > 0 ? (int)Math.Pow(2, index) : 0));
result.Remove(0);
```

Edit 2:

```
HashSet<uint> result = new HashSet<uint>(str.Reverse().Select((c, index) => 
                              int.Parse(c.ToString()) > 0 ? (uint)Math.Pow(2, index) : 0));
result.Remove(0);
```

Comment: Index start at most significant bit, but your query use it like it start at least significant. Also oveflow will occur in this query for `uint.MaxValue`, `(int)Math.Pow(2, 31)` equals `-2147483648`.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev - just edited, as I mentioned it works only for `int`s just because there's no `Convert.ToString` taking `uint` and `base`

Comment: That's true, but there is a version that accept `long` and base. You can use it with `uint` because it will be implicitly converted to `long`. `Convert.ToString(uint.MaxValue, 2)` works fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually even `Convert.ToString((int)sum, 2)` works fine, because regardless of oveflow `sum` and `(int)sum` two's complements are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the obvious loop and not bother with Linq:

```
private HashSet<uint> ExtractTrueBitsFromSum(uint sum)
{
    var set = new HashSet<uint>();

    for (uint j = 1; j != 0; j <<= 1)
        if ((sum & j) != 0)
            set.Add(j);

    return set;
}
```

Comment: You can drop `i` and use `j != 0` as loop condition.

Comment: @PetSerAl True, as long as I then put `unchecked` around it. (Or maybe that's not needed - I'll check)

Comment: Ok I tested it, and you don't need `unchecked`.

Answer (score 0):

I thnik it's not any reason for using LINQ.

```
private static HashSet<uint> ExtractTrueBitsFromSum(uint sum)
{
    var result = new HashSet<uint>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        if (((sum >> i) & 0x1) == 1)
            result.Add((uint)((1 << i)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer LINQ:

```
private HashSet<uint> ExtractTrueBitsFromSum(uint sum)
{
    var bits = Convert.ToString(sum, toBase: 2);
    return new HashSet<uint>(
                bits.Select((bit, index) => (uint)(bit - '0') << (bits.Length - index - 1))
                    .Where(pow => pow > 0));
}
```